# Where to find fracture xray imaging data?

Tags: data-request, medical

Where can I retrieve X-ray image data of fractures?

Labeled data containing features like age, type of fracture would be best.

Answer (score 1):

This [Github repo](https://github.com/beamandrew/medical-data) has a long list of Medical Imagining datasets.

In particular:

**[Emergency Tele-Orthopedics X-ray Digital Library](http://www.medinfo.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/downloads/datasets)**

[image]

[Journal article](http://www.medinfo.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/downloads/datasets/735-emergency-teleorthopaedics-m-health-system-for-wireless-communication-links) abstract:

> For the first time, a complete wireless and mobile emergency TeleOrthoPaedics system with field trials and expert opinion is presented. The system enables doctors in a remote area to obtain a second opinion from doctors in the hospital using secured wireless telecommunication networks. Doctors can exchange securely medical images and video as well as other important data, and thus perform remote consultations, fast and accurately using a user friendly interface, via a reliable and secure telemedicine system of low cost. The quality of the transmitted compressed (JPEG2000) images was measured using different metrics and doctors opinions. The results have shown that all metrics were within acceptable limits. The performance of the system was evaluated successfully under different wireless communication links based on real data.

Unfortunately, the download link is not valid, but can likely be found by <s>the wayback machine (archive.org) or by</s>* contacting the authors/webmaster.

```
http://www.medinfo.cs.ucy.ac.cy/doc/Publications/Datasets/images_orthop.zip
```

* *not archived by wayback machine*